# Pop-up Window opens larger in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html

The site has media player that pops-up when the user clicks play. On all browsers the pop-up window renders at the specified size of 655px in height. But in Firefox the window renders a lot longer like 200px extra. The width is correct.

Using the onClick script:

```
onclick="window.open('Media-player.html','player','scrollbars=0,width=360,height=655')"
```

What's Firefox's problem? Thanks.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsbin.com/enevol I get the same size window using Chrome, Opera, and Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual link in question did not have the comma between the width and height. Apparently FF is picky about the commas...thx